# Is it possible to use a zmq::poll() on a ZMQ_PAIR socket archetype?

Tags: zeromq

Is it possible to use **`zmq::poll`** with a socket of type **`ZMQ_PAIR`**? I have the following code:

```
zmq::context_t ctx;

// create an in-process publisher for testing purposes
zmq::socket_t pub( ctx, ZMQ_PAIR );
pub.connect( "inproc://SelectTest_oneMessage" );
SendString( pub, "test-message" );

// create an in-process subscriber for testing purposes
zmq::socket_t sub( ctx, ZMQ_PAIR );
sub.bind( "inproc://SelectTest_oneMessage" );

zmq::pollitem_t sel[1];
sel[0].socket = &sub;
sel[0].events = ZMQ_POLLIN;

int rc = zmq::poll( sel, 1, -1 );
ASSERT_TRUE( sel[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN );

zmq::message_t msg;
ASSERT_NE( sub.recv( &msg ), 0 );
ASSERT_NE( sub.recv( &msg ), 0 );
```

But the call to `zmq::poll` fails with an exception:

> **`Socket operation on non-socket`**

What am I doing wrong here? Or is this expected behavior for `ZMQ_PAIR` sockets?

Comment: What value does the **`rc`** actually get from `.poll()`?

Comment: The exception is thrown inside the call to zmq::poll, so, since I'm using the c++ zmq wrappers, I never get a return value.

Comment: The exception seems to me to be initiated from the `SendString()`, declared somewhat similar to `inline void SendString( zmq::socket_t& sock, const std::string& s ) throw ( zmq::error_t ) { ... }` not from the `zmq::poll()` per-se. May trace in detail, step-by-step, as proposed below.

Comment: Hi @user3666197. What is the justification for reformatting the OP's code in the fashion that you have? I get that you like bracket spacing in you own code, and in your own prose, but it does not feel appropriate to be forcing other people to use your preferred coding standards. I wouldn't mention if it if it was just this case, but you seem to be energetically forcing this on a lot of other people's posts. I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: I learn a lot from you, sir. **Forcing?** Whom? Btw, you might have noticed, that I have solved several troubles for the Alex and helped him learn about ZeroMQ problem domain -- **have you ever noticed this principal added value, that people expect** from StackOverflow posts?

Comment: That's a separate question @user3666197, and not relevant to the point I am making. I can't compel you to give me a straightforward answer, and would not wish to, but I'd be interested in an answer if you can supply one. (Reminder: please use my handle if you wish to reply to me, I saw your response now by chance).

Comment: I did provide you an explicit answer in my previous comment. Later, the **previous comment was deleted by someone else**, by using some  administrative privilege. Censorship has never created any understanding. **Demeanor of censorship is a sign of a mis-use of powers**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was this line:

```
sel[0].socket = &sub;
```

The `&` should not have been there. The code works after changing this to:

```
sel[0].socket = sub;
```

It was difficult to catch this problem because the `socket` field of that struct is a `void *`, which means that the type checker does not complain in either case.

Comment: Sure, sir. The complete solution, including the correct type of this assignment **`sel[0].socket = sub;` was posted already two days ago** ( since rev. 2 ).

Answer (score 2):

### No, it is not forbidden to `.poll()` on `ZMQ_PAIR` endpoint ( `sub` )

The trouble seems with **`.connect()`** before **`.bind()`**

API says this *( emphasis added )*:

> When connecting a socket to a peer address using `zmq_connect()` with the **`inproc`** transport, the endpoint shall be interpreted as an arbitrary string identifying the name to connect to. **Before version 4.0 he name must have been previously created by assigning it to at least one socket within the same ØMQ context as the socket being connected.** Since version 4.0 the order of `zmq_bind()` and `zmq_connect()` does not matter just like for the tcp transport type.

---

### Catch the exact point, where the dog is burried:

```
//                                                                      >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44510552
//  Report 0MQ version
//
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
int                major,  minor,  patch;
zmq_version (     &major, &minor, &patch );                             std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ USES 0MQ-API version" << major << "." << minor << "." << patch                                << std::endl;
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */ 
zmq::context_t      pure_inproc_ctx( 0 );                               std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ CREATED a Zero-IOthreads .Context()-instance for pure-inproc:// transport-classes operations" << std::endl;
zmq::socket_t  pub( pure_inproc_ctx, ZMQ_PAIR );                        std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ DONE [pub] socket instantiation" << std::endl;
zmq::socket_t  sub( pure_inproc_ctx, ZMQ_PAIR );                        std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ DONE [sub] socket instantiation" << std::endl;

sub.setsockopt( ZMQ_LINGER, 0, 1 );                 /* .setsockopt() */ std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ DONE [sub].setsockopt()"         << std::endl;
sub.bind(      "inproc://SelectTest_oneMessage" );  /* .bind()       */ std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ DONE [sub].bind()"               << std::endl;

pub.setsockopt( ZMQ_LINGER, 0, 1 );                 /* .setsockopt() */ std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ DONE [pub].setsockopt()"         << std::endl;
pub.connect(   "inproc://SelectTest_oneMessage" );  /* .connect()    */ std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ DONE [pub].connect()"            << std::endl;

zmq::message_t  aMessageToSEND ( 5 );
     memcpy (   aMessageToSEND.data (), "Hello", 5 );                   std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ CREATED a [Hello] Message"       << std::endl;

pub.send (      aMessageToSEND );                                       std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ SENT a Message via [pub].send()" << std::endl;

zmq::pollitem_t      sel[1];
                     sel[0].socket = sub;
                     sel[0].events = ZMQ_POLLIN;                        std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ DONE a .Poller() setup"          << std::endl;
                                                                        std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ WILL wait HERE infinitely for a first .Poller.poll() for a [sub].POLLIN Event"   << std::endl;
int rc = zmq::poll( &sel [0], 1, -1 );                                  std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ EXIT from wait-state on a first .Poller.poll() [sub].POLLIN Event"               << std::endl;

ASSERT_TRUE(         sel[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN );                     std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ DONE test on a first .Poller.poll() [sub].POLLIN Event"                          << std::endl;

zmq::message_t        aMessageToRECV;                                   std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ CREATED a aMessageToRECV Message-container instance"                             << std::endl;
ASSERT_NE( sub.recv( &aMessageToRECV ), 0 );                            std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ DONE 1st test on [sub].recv() to immediately load aMessageToRECV-container"      << std::endl;
ASSERT_NE( sub.recv( &aMessageToRECV ), 0 );                            std::cout << "[INF] ZeroMQ DONE 2nd test on [sub].recv() to immediately load an already loaded container"   << std::endl;
```